# Could not connect to Bitcoin RPC server outside local host using bitcoind-0.18.0

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

I upgrade bitcoin core from **0.16.3** to **0.18.0**, But I can not connect to RPC server outside local host.

I use the following parameters as bitcoin.conf:

```
testnet=1
server=1
daemon=1
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
rpcuser=xxxxxx
rpcpassword=xxxxxxx
[test]
rpcport=8383 
wallet=test_btc_wallet.dat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly bind it to 0.0.0.0 by using `rpcbind=0.0.0.0`

Read Andrew Chow's detailed response: [Can't reach remote bitcoin rpc server](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/88947/cant-reach-remote-bitcoin-rpc-server)